# Not sure why node.js pipe is hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to essentially pipe two console commands together, but I'm clearly missing something:

```
var child = require('child_process');

var image_bin = child.spawn('cat', ['./t.jpg']);
var image_txt = child.spawn('openssl', ['base64']);

image_txt.on('pipe', function(src) {
  console.error('something is piping into the writer');
});

image_bin.stdout.pipe(image_txt.stdout);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're redirecting `stdout` to `stdout`? It won't work :)

Comment: Thanks @IvanGrynko, that was the last thing I tried.  image_bin.stdout.pipe(image_txt.stdin); hangs as well, is that what you were thinking would work?

Comment: Are you trying to just base64 encode an image?

Comment: @dylants I'm sure your going to suggest some npm that does exactly that, but I'm more interested in learning how to pipe to commands together.

Comment: No actually, I was going to suggest a different way of coding this up with Node's Buffer's and Stream's, but I understand, and I won't do that :)  I'm not sure if the openssl command will wait for input from standard in, but you should change that pipe to send it to `image_txt.stdin` and then change the `on` to `image_txt.stdin.on('pipe'`.  With those changes, you'll at least see the `console.error` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @IvanGrynko and @dylants.  I definitly needed to change stdout to stdin.  @dylants I tried different variations of looking for errors on stdin, stderr and stdout, but didn't see any.  However when I started monitoring for data on stdout things started working.  When I think about it I guess that makes sense.  I guess it blocks if you don't actually do something with the data.  Here is what I came up with:

```
var child = require('child_process');

var image_bin = child.spawn('cat', ['./t.jpg']);
var image_txt = child.spawn('openssl', ['base64']);

image_txt.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});

image_bin.stdout.pipe(image_txt.stdin);
```